# Dell Poweredge 2970 Performance problems

Tags: dell-poweredge

We have dell poweredge 2970 with 16GB ram, running windows server 2008 enterprise, running Hyper-V with two VMs using total ram of 4GB. It's also running SQL server 2005.
One of the VMs is a web server and the other an exchange server.
This machine for no reasons freezes sometimes and we have to manually restart it.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Most server-grade hardware platforms contain a hardware event log that you can probably get into on the BIOS screen; look into it the next time you need to reboot the machine. With any luck, this will give you some indication of where to start looking for a hardware issue, which will make it easier to get an engineer onsite to verify and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Either outdated drivers, or a case of RMA need. Or, in simple words: either your sysadmin did not do his job keeping drivers current, or the hardware is broken and needs to be repaired / replaced.

Could be anything in the hardware. MOtherboard, RAM. Start testing if you want. If it is warranty, just call Dell.

Btw., system freezing is not a performance problem.

Comment: blaming you overworked sysadmin is not a good way to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

I only upgraded the BIOS, it was so old and so far everything is working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many components of [Dell OpenManage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenManage) will tell you if any hardware errors occured, such as an unrecoverable ECC Memory error or CPU fault.

[Dell Server Update Utility](http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/OpenManage+Server+Update+Utility+-+SUU) will tell you what needs updating.

If your SysAdmin didn't install any OpenManager components, or hasn't run SUU lately, ask him or her why, and what they are using instead. If Windows updates are run regularly, they ASSUME that corresponding BIOS and driver updates are installed along with them. If Windows Update is run regularly and other components are not updated, you will have new problems occuring on an irregular basis.